# how to get variables from a script my player is colliding with?

Tags: unity-game-engine

so i have my player standing next to a cube. the player has a script, which is empty aside from an int which is 43. the same applies to the cube except the int in the cube's script is 42. how do i get(or detect) the int in the cube's script and print it in the console using OnCollisionEnter(or OnTriggerEnter if it is better) like this: ("the cube has the number 42")?

Comment: This question has several basic components that are critical in understand Unity and coding in general. I would highly advise checking out some [tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) first. Additionally, when asking a question such as this, show your code, what isn't working, and what you've tried.

Comment: ah thanks for the answer, if i can't get it to work i will just come here or ask it in other helpful places

Answer (score 1):

Well you should *definitely* go through some tutorials before continuing since you don't seem to know even very basic stuff, but to at least point you in the right direction, you would do something like this (assuming C#, not UnityScript):

```csharp
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
  int numberOfCollidedObject = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<objectsScriptNameHere>().variableNameHere;
  Debug.Log(numberOfCollidedObject);
}
```

How did I know how to do that? I looked at [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html). I can see that when `OnCollisionEnter` is called it's passed a variable of type `Collision`. It's hyperlinked in the documentation, so I clicked on `Collision` and found that it contains a variable called `gameObject` that contains a reference to the game object of the collider we just hit. I happen to know that to get into another script, you called `GetComponent<scriptName>()`, and from there any public variables and functions can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

if you got two collider (player and object who collide the player) you can convex the collider and set [isTrigger](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders-triggers) to true

Then call the function [OnTriggerEnter()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html)

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    Debug.Log(other.name);
}
```